# How to create an environment that contains shownto from multiaudience package?

Tags: errors, environments

Is it possible to create an environment that contains `shownto` environment from `multiaudience` package?

With the following MWE I got the error `! LaTeX Error: \begin{shownto} on input line 26 ended by \end{cmcomment}.`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{others}
\SetNewAudience{onlyme} 
\DefCurrentAudience{onlyme} 

\newenvironment{cmcomment}{%
    \begin{shownto}{onlyme}\textcolor{gray}\small\singlespacing%
    }{\end{shownto}}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
Everyone read this \blindtext
\begin{cmcomment}
I read this \blindtext
\end{cmcomment}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `\newenvironment` you could use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` with the `b`-type argument:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{others}
\SetNewAudience{onlyme} 
\DefCurrentAudience{onlyme} 

\NewDocumentEnvironment{cmcomment}{+b}
  {%
    \begin{shownto}{onlyme}%
      \color{gray}\small
      \singlespacing%
      #1\par%
    \end{shownto}%
  }
  {}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{otcomment}{+b}
  {%
    \begin{shownto}{others}%
      \color{gray}\small
      \singlespacing
      #1\par
    \end{shownto}%
  }
  {}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
Everyone read this \blindtext

\begin{cmcomment}
I read this \blindtext
\end{cmcomment}

Everyone read this \blindtext
\begin{otcomment}
Others read this \blindtext
\end{otcomment}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @CarLaTeX add a `\par` before `\begin{cmcomment}` for the `\doublespacing` to take effect on the first paragraph. Though somehow the `\singlespacing` from `cmcomment` seems to be leaking out... Maybe an extra group and a `\par` helps there.

Comment: @CarLaTeX blame `multiaudience` for being weird. Assuming your contents are always fine to be read as a macro parameter you could use `\ExplSyntaxOn \str_new:N \l_carlatex_audience_str \NewDocumentCommand \setaudience { m } { \str_set:Nn \l_carlatex_audience_str {#1} } \NewDocumentEnvironment { shownto } { m b } { \str_if_eq:VnT \l_carlatex_audience_str {#1} {#2} } {}`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX `\textcolor` doesn't work because it reads `\small` as its argument, you want to use `\color` instead to change the colour of your environment.

Comment: Oh, what a silly error :D It works

Comment: And you have to end the paragraph before changing the line spacing if you want your changes to apply. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you! And sorry again for my error

Comment: @CarLaTeX don't worry, it happens :P